# For some reason i cant save more than one thing on a list(while it is on a for loop)

Tags: python, list

```
from random import choice

# List of anime

anime = [['One Punch Man','Funny','NotBig'],['One piece','NotFunny','Big'],
['MyHeroAc','NotFunny','NotBig']]

#input

mood = input('What anime do you want:')
#print random anime
for item in anime:
    if item[1] == mood:
        k = item[0]
        print(mood + ' anime = ' + item [0])
        mood_list = list()
        mood_list.append(k)


print('Do you want a radnom one from the', mood,'anime; Y/N')

ch = input()

if ch == 'Y':
    print(mood_list) #make it pick a random anime of the funny cadigory
    print(len(mood_list))
```

So as you can see i want to save the item[0] from the anime list to mood_list but only the names of the one that have the specific mood type... for some reason i cant find a way to save 2 of the names of the anime. I save the name of the anime in k and then i append it to the mood_list but it the mood_list at the end holds only the last anime that has the specific mood(it cant save more than 2 anime with the same mood) pls help

Comment: Define `mood_list = list()` (or more idiomatically, `mood_list = []`) *before* entering the `for` loop. As is you replace it with an empty `list` before each `append`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop, you are re-defining the list each time that you run `mood_list=list()`. Instead, you'll want to do something like this:

```
mood = input('What anime do you want:')
mood_list = []
#print random anime
for item in anime:
  if item[1] == mood:
    k = item[0]
    print(mood + ' anime = ' + item [0])
    mood_list.append(k)
```

Comment: you could also use f-strings here